# What is Autoit equivalent for VBA Collection object?

Tags: vba, autoit

What is Autoit equivalent for VBA Collection object?

```
Dim CollArrays As New Collection 'VBA Collection
```

How can create collection of 2D arrays with Autoit?

Add more details.

```
#include <Array.au3>
_Example()

Func _Example()
    Local $a_1[2][2] = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
    Local $a_2[2][2]= [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
    Local $a_3[2][2]= [[8, 9], [10, 11]]

    numRows = UBound($a_1(1), 1)
    numCols = UBound(@a_2(1), 2)

    Local $a_outer = [1 To (numRows*@a_outer.length)] [1 to numCols]

    ; get current $a_2
    $a_2 = $a_outer[1]

    ; add element to $a_2
    _ArrayAdd($a_2, 12, 13)

    ; put them back to $a_outer
    $a_outer[1] = $a_2

 EndFunc

 MsgBox(0, "", _Example())
```

Write Error.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You could use Array.au3 in Autoit and _ArrayAdd to add items to your array.

Comment: Xenobiologist, Target: combine multiple 2D arrays into single 2D array.

Comment: _ArrayConcatenate ???

Comment: Note that AutoIt-Arrays are able to hold arrays ("Array of arrays")

Comment: Xenobiologist, need to use _ArrayAdd in loop For Each and use UBound 2D arrays.

Comment: why you declare `Local $a_2[2][2]` twice ?

Comment: Please read more about using arrays in AutoIt as this `Local $a_outer = (1 To (numRows*@a_outer.length), 1 to numCols))` is not correct way to enumerate array rows.

Comment: Michał Lipok, I declare Local $a_2[2][2] is 2D array.

Comment: Your's way of `Local $a_outer` declaration is wrong. Take a look again on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Array.au3>

_Example()

Func _Example()
    Local $a_1[2] = [0, 1]
    Local $a_2[2] = [2, 3]
    Local $a_outer[2] = [$a_1, $a_2]
    
    ; get current $a_2
    $a_2 = $a_outer[1]
    
    ; add element to $a_2
    _ArrayAdd($a_2, 4)
    
    ; put them back to $a_outer
    $a_outer[1] = $a_2
    
EndFunc
```

Comment: And Xenobiologist, answer `need to use _ArrayAdd in loop For Each and use UBound 2D arrays` will be usefull in your case.